# function in a cell is not executing initially when i add data through userform

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Data is entered into cells using userfaorm, then this function

`"=IFERROR(INDEX(PARTNO_BRAL,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A3,PARTNO_BRAL),0)),"")"`

should read data from cell that is entered by userform. But this function does nt work until i enter in the next row. Please suggest how i can fix this?

PARTNO_BRAL is a dynamic range.

Comment: What do you mean by enter in the Next Row ? What is `PARTNO_BRAL` in your Function above ? We cannot answer unless we understand the problem completely. Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do ? Read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: PARTNO_BRAL is a Dynamic range.i am unable to attach images or files. i am unable to explain here without attachments.